# Add children controls within a ServerControl tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, servercontrols

I'm working on a Navigation Menu.
I've created below ServerControl and it works, but I want to allow users adding some standard ASP.NET controls within my ServerControl Tags like `label`, `image` and so on.

```
<MdsMenu:ServerControlMenu ID="ServerControlMenu1" runat="server">
  <MdsMenu:animation AnimationSpeed="Normal" AnimationType="Opacity_Height" Delay="1000" DropShadow="true" />
    <!-- HERE HAS TO HAVE SOME STANDARD ASP.NET CONTROLS -->
    <!-- e.g <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> -->
  </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
</MdsMenu:ServerControlMenu>
```

My problem is here that how I can get Child Controls within `<MdsMenu:MenuItem>` and show them like as they are in the output.

P.S: 
I overwrite `RenderContents` method

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{ 
   output.Write(OutPutStringBuilder.ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you will just have to throw `[ParseChildren(false), PersistChildren(true)]` on the class that represents the `<MdsMenu:MenuItem/>` tag.  Child controls written inside the tag should then be available at runtime in the control's `Controls` property.

**UPDATE:** I threw together a quick test project to demonstrate that this actually works.  (Apparently people like to downvote without actually evaluating whether an answer is correct.)

This custom control has the behavior you would expect:

```
[ParseChildren(false), PersistChildren(true)]
public partial class SuperDiv : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<div class=\"super\">");
        writer.Write(Controls.Count);

        foreach (Control i in Controls)
            i.RenderControl(writer);

        writer.Write("</div>");
    }
}
```

So the following ASP.NET markup:

```
<test:SuperDiv runat="server">
    <asp:Label runat="server">Hello, World!</asp:Label>
</test:SuperDiv>
```

Will result in the following HTML being rendered:

```
<div class="super">3
    <span>Hello, World!</span>
</div>
```

(3 because the two text nodes containing only whitespace are also children of the control, as well as the label.)

Comment: can you maybe provide an article about why adding "[ParseChildren(false), PersistChildren(true)]" is the solution, it seems like an obscure solution.

Comment: @Letseatlunch - see the remarks section of the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistchildrenattribute.aspx The PersistChildrenAttribute is used in combination with the ParseChildrenAttribute to determine how nested content of a control is interpreted. If PersistChildrenAttribute is true and ParseChildrenAttribute is false, the nested content contained within an ASP.NET server control is persisted as controls. If PersistChildrenAttribute is false and ParseChildrenAttribute is true, the nested content is persisted as properties of the server control.

Comment: this solution seems to work except if doesn't handle these kind of things <%= String.Format("{0}.blah","091") %> or just plain text

Comment: It should support plain text too... I will have a look at it in the morning and see what I can come up with.

Comment: If the controls within `SuperDiv` were nested, how we can render them ?

Comment: You don't render the children of your own child tags -- you ask your direct descendants to render themselves and *they* will render their *own* children.

Comment: @Letseatlunch: This solution *does* work for plain text -- I just tested it.  Plain text contained inside the control tag will be converted into an instance of `System.Web.UI.LiteralControl`.  With this loop, I get all of the text and contained ASP.NET controls rendered as expected: `public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) { foreach (Control i in Controls) i.RenderControl(writer); }`

Answer (score 1):

you need to make your web control act as a container (like the panel control)

just add the attributes showed below to your web user control class

```
 [ParseChildren(false)]
    [PersistChildren(true)]
    [Designer(typeof(PanelDesigner))] 
    public class MyOwnControl:WebControl
    {




    }
```

then on the .aspx page you will be able to do the below:

```
 <cc1:MyOwnControl ID="MyOwnControl1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </cc1:MyOwnControl>
```